# TIFs on GCS corruption issues

Tags: image-processing, google-cloud-storage, photoshop, tiff

I've been using Google Cloud Storage to store TIF files since last December. Just recently we've been getting a lot of errors on our TIF files, many of which we've been able to download and view successfully months ago, and similar errors on more recently uploaded images. The TIFs are coming out as corrupted in a way where the image doesn't fully show, but the bottom 80% or 20% or 40% (you get the picture) will be black, or if not black the same row of pixels repeated continuously for the rest of the height of the image.

[image: Example of corrupted image display]

paint.net gave me the best error about it:

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.`

`at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)`

Photoshop gives one of these two errors:

`There was an error reading the file's metadata. This document may be damaged (the file may be truncated or incomplete). Continue?`

`Could not complete your request because an unexpected end-of-file was encountered.`

Any ideas on how to solve for this? Is there a way to restore images? Script idea for fixing metadata and color profiles? This problem is causing a trickle down of problems for me right now so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have the files in GCS been overwritten recently? There should be timestamps for each new item. Alternately, have you recently upgraded your TIF reading library/program?

Comment: Good thought on the timestamp/overwrite - I just confirmed timestamps have not been changed. The glitch occurs on multiple computers in multiple countries and every TIF reading software that's been attempted, I've tested 5 programs myself.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have an original copy of the TIF that works? Could you perhaps download the remote version and see if you get the same bytes?